# Pushing an element into an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, object-literal

I'm new to React, but I'm pretty sure this question is more related to Javascript than React. I want to push a custom element into an object that has already been made in React, without triggering a `forceUpdate()`.

I want to push `fullName` to the `person` object. so I can access it in React like this, `this.state.person.fullName` rather than `this.state.fullName`.

Now I know I could do: `this.state.person.fullName = this.formatName(person.name)`.

But that requires `forceUpdate()` to trigger a re-render., which is not the recommended way I think.

```
class Person extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.url = "https://randomuser.me/api";
        this.state = {
            person: {
                fullName: '',
            },

        };

        this.generate = this.generate.bind(this);
    }

    formatName(name) {
        // Mr.Jon Snow
        return `${name.title}.${name.first} ${name.last}`;
    }
    generate() {
        axios.get(this.url).then(response => {
            var person = response.data.results[0];
            this.setState({
                person: person,
                fullName: this.formatName(person.name)
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.generate}>Generate</button>
                <div className="card">
                    <h3>The person's information</h3>
                    <div className="person-name">Name: {this.state.fullName}</div>
                    <div className="person-dob">Date of Birth: {this.state.person.dob}</div>
                    <div className="person-email">Email: {this.state.person.email}</div>
                    <div className="person-phone">Phone Number: {this.state.person.phone}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Person />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var person = response.data.results[0];
person.fullName = this.formatName(person.name);
this.setState({
    person: person,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ES6 Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to make the change as you requested.

**Example**

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  person: {
    ...prevState.person,
    fullName: this.formatName(person.name)
  }
}))
```

**Update** *(I misunderstood the problem. This is more relevant to the question)*

```
let person = response.data.results[0];
person["fullName"] = this.formatName(person.name);
this.setState({
  person: person
});
```

Comment: Now the person object's properties are empty, but the fullName is displayed... could it be because I don't use a compiler?

Comment: @Akar I updated the answer. I suppose I got what you asked wrong at first. Please try and see if the second example helps.

Comment: Both you and Pratheep, solved the problem, but his solution is what I prefer, I still upvoted both of the answers though, thanks for taking your time.

Comment: @akar, you can use `Object.assign` method (like in my answer) if you are using `ES6`. in order to write a clear solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` method in order to achieve your requirement.

```
var person = response.data.results[0];
Object.assign(person,{"fullName": this.formatName(person.name)};
this.state = {
     person: person
};
```